# How can I swip/flip/slide tab control with gesture?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

How can I swipe/flip/slide tab control with gesture, like in flipboard or lumi app ?

I think I can start from the example here, but I don't know how to handle it with gestures.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/FMX.TSwipeTransitionEffect_Animation

edit : I'm looking for Delphi/firemonkey solutions.

**update1** :

I'm thinking about following scenario :

first take screenshot of 2 tabs/controls I want to flip/slide. then use SwipeTransitionEffect on that 2 images combining with gesture .. after completion hide the image, show the tabs.  just a thought. I don't know yet how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Viewpage` with `TabLayout`. Setup `ViewPager` with the `Views` / `Fragments` you need to swipe between. Then attach a `TabLayout` to the `ViewPager`. This setup comes with swipe gesture response built in.

A tutorial Link : https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

This is really gonna help you out.